# MariaDB: to order by specific Column_A value and Column_B

Tags: mariadb

I have a table like:

```
+-------------------+-----------+
| FieldId           | FieldValue|
+-------------------+-----------+
| field_klsciv50    | Apple     |
| field_kbgankim    | Fish      |
| field_klsciv50    | Banana    |
| field_kijagc5r    | Cow       |
| field_kijagc5r    | Dog       |
| field_klsciv50    | Orange    |
+-------------------+-----------+
```

How do I make it so the order is:

```
+-------------------+-----------+
| FieldId           | FieldValue|
+-------------------+-----------+
| field_klsciv50    | Apple     |
| field_klsciv50    | Banana    |
| field_klsciv50    | Orange    |
| field_kijagc5r    | Cow       |
| field_kijagc5r    | Dog       |
| field_kbgankim    | Fish      |
+-------------------+-----------+
```

Can't figure out how to order it by Fruit Field with its `FieldId` of `field_klsciv50` and the values above.

Thanks!

Comment: You want the order in your table to be like this or from a query? For a query, just `ORDER BY FieldId DESC, FieldValue`

Comment: @Scratte thanks, It should be FieldId Specific, In the case above only the records with `field_klsciv50` FieldId should only be sorted.

Comment: You can't do that. You can sort your result set or not sort your result set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the table on a `FieldId` value, sort the half that you wantand then combine them again:

```
SELECT FieldId, FieldValue
FROM
    (SELECT FieldId, FieldValue
     FROM MyTable
     WHERE FieldId = 'field_klsciv50'
     ORDER BY FieldValue
    )
UNION ALL
SELECT FieldId, FieldValue
FROM MyTable
WHERE FieldId != 'field_klsciv50'
```

Comment: Nice @Frank it worked